# In IE9 Quirks Mode Date.parse returns NaN

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iso, quirks-mode

I am trying to figure out why Date.parse (javascript) returns NaN when applied to a seemingly valid ISO 8601 date string when IE9 is in Quirks Mode.  It works fine in Standards mode.

```
//ReturnsNaN in Quirks Mode, 1270574382557 in Standards Mode
document.write(Date.parse("2010-04-06T17:19:42.557"));  

//Returns NaN in Quirks Mode, 1270512000000 in Standards Mode
document.write(Date.parse("2010-04-06"));
```

In contrast, the following works in both Quirks and Standards for me

```
//Returns 1270549182000 in both Quirks and Standards Modes  
document.write(Date.parse("2010/04/06T17:19:42"));
```

Is anybody else seeing this behavior?  If so, any ideas on why Date.parse is returning NaN?

Comment: Perhaps this will help, perhaps not: [Two similar Date.parse cases return different results.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should understand that quirks mode is basically an IE5 compatibility mode.

It is triggered by not having a valid  declaration. 
The main effect is that it causes the browser to use the IE5 box-model, which means that all your paddings, margins and borders, and anything else which affects the size of a box will be incorrect.

So your Date.parse doesn't work because there were no such feature - "parse ISO 8601 date" at those dates.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for the info!  I knew about the box-model, bu I did not realize that Quirks affected dates, et al.